# Cant open and edit .bash_profile on my Mac

Tags: android, macos, cordova, terminal

I want to build an app with Eclipse and PhoneGap, and it is required to edit the .bash_profile file which is located under the `Users` folder. But I can't edit it (I can't open the file). [Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html) are the instructions.

I can't open it when I navigate with the `Finder` to that file, and I can't open it when I use the command line

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

I created the file with my mouse (right click, new file, and changed the name to `.bash_profile` ... it is now a shell script).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, files starting with a dot (.) are hidden, simply edit the file, and everything is okay.

So you can for example do
nano ~/.bash_profile
or
vim ~/.bash_profile
or whichever favorite editor you are using.

Comment: thanks that was right. and i was also able to edit it with my code editor :)

Answer (score 3):

You can see your ~/.bash_profile if you start the Terminal application and type:

```
ls -a
```

into the Terminal window, since the "-a" option shows even hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

Can use vi editors with the following comment to open the file to edit in terminal

```
vi .bash_profile
```

Can user (E) to edit the respective file[image]

For more useful comments like insert and save on vi editor [refer](https://www.guru99.com/the-vi-editor.html)